# How to Label Speech data For end to end speech to text training

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I've been wondering that i have some audio data which contains **recorded sentences** so when i will use this data to train a neural network how will i label this audio sentence file do i have to just mention the work present in the audio file or should i label with character by character of a audio time interval. so if any one can give me an idea how to actually **label the audio data** to train a neural network and what will be the **output of the neural network**.